# Dealing With ArcPad and Geodatabase Domains

Tags: arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase, fields-attributes, arcpad, domains

I created a polygon feature class through a file geodatabase. In the geodatabase i created domains and gave them drop downs. When i go to create a feature class in editor in ArcGIS, in the attribute i am allowed to see dropdowns. However when i use ArcPad i get a empty text box rather than a drop down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you getting the data over to ArcPad?  Is it coverted to an AXF file?

Comment: It might be good to provide some more information. Are you using custom edit forms? How are you exporting the data for Arcpad? Are you using AXF? If it's using shapefiles those don't support domains.

Comment: So everything works in ArcGIS. I am using a geodatabase feature class and not a shapefile. However the drop down does not appear in the ArcPad, which would confirm that mistake haha.                                                                      I am exporting apm, apl,dbf,prj,shp, shx, and ssf files to the ArcPad. You mentioned AXF, i don't get that is that the issue?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with these clarifications and any extra details that you think would help to attract a potential answerer.